# Typescript errors only on GitHub Actions

Tags: typescript, github-actions, pnpm

I have a React+Vite project and below Dockerfile. When I run this locally all works fine. But on GitHub actions I get errors like `Cannot find module '@/components/ui/Button' or its corresponding type declarations` and `error TS7006: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type`

```
FROM node:20-slim AS nodebase
ENV PNPM_HOME="/pnpm"
ENV PATH="$PNPM_HOME:$PATH"
RUN corepack enable
COPY ./frontend/app /app
WORKDIR /app

FROM nodebase AS nodebuild
RUN --mount=type=cache,id=pnpm,target=/pnpm/store pnpm install --frozen-lockfile
RUN pnpm run build
```

I deleted my node_modules directory locally, cleared Docker image cache, deleted pnpm store files and still not able to replicate this locally.
I am not sure why I get these errors on GitHub actions only.

Comment: It's not clear from your question, the code runs locally, but can you build the container locally? Using something like `docker build -t debug .`

Comment: Yes it was working locally. Posted the answer. A silly mistake on which I spent several hours.  :(

Answer (score 1):

To debug the issue I added below to my Dockerfile which listed the TS config and files and I compared this output to the one on my local machine.

```
RUN pnpm tsc --showConfig
```

It turned out that I had changed the casing of a few filenames, eg. I renamed button.tsx to Button.tsx. This was not detected by Git and the file in repo was still having lowercase B.

I used `git mv` to rename the files again and pushed the changes. After this is started working.